# How do I get the 'initials' of a contact's middle name?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to get the exchange user's middle name initials.

[image]

```
Function getFullName(exchangeUser As ExchangeUser) As String
    Dim firstName, middleName, lastName, As String
    firstName = exchangeUser.GetExchangeUser.firstName
    middleName = exchangeUser.GetExchangeUser.{somehow retrieve middle name}
    lastName = exchangeUser.GetExchangeUser.lastName
    getFullName = firstName & " " & middleName & " " & lastName
End Function
```

I tried `GetExchangeUser.fullName` but that does not return the middle initials.

I tried:

```
Function getFullName(exchangeUser As ExchangeUser) As String
    Dim firstName, middleName, lastName, As String
    Dim propName As String
    propName = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3A44001F"
    firstName = exchangeUser.GetExchangeUser.firstName
    middleName = exchangeUser.GetExchangeUser.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(propName)
    lastName = exchangeUser.GetExchangeUser.lastName
    getFullName = firstName & " " & middleName & " " & lastName
End Function
```

I get an error that the property is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve the `PR_MIDDLE_NAME` MAPI property using AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty. The DALS property name is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3A44001F`

Comment: So I tried this and I am getting an error saying that the property is not found.

Comment: I did 'propName = http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3A44001F' and 'middleName = exchangeUser.GetExchangeUser.PropertyyAccessor.GetProperty(propName)' and the property was not found

Comment: That means it does not exist for that particular GAL entry. Take a look at GAL in OutlookSpy - click IAddrBook | Open Root Container | GetHierarchyTable | GetContentsTable, etc. Or if oy uhave the GAL entry as a recipient in a message, select the message, click IMessage, go to the GetRecipeintTable, double click on the recipient.